# Get Elasticsearch match based on list of values

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using Logstash to input data from my database to Elasticsearch.
For an specific SQL query, I have one column that retrieves values as a CSV, like "role1;role2;role3".
This column is being indexed as a regular string in Elastic.

**The problem:**
I need to make an Elastic query on that field based on another list of values.

**For example**: On the java side I have a collection with the values: "role3", "role4", "role5" and based on that I should get all the records in Elastic that matches "role3", "role4" or "role5".

In this specific case, my elastic data is like this:

```
"_source": {
  "userName": "user1",
  "roles": "role1;role2;role3"  
}
"_source": {
  "userName": "user2",
  "roles": "role7;role8;role9"  
}
```

In this case it should return the record for "user1", as it gets a match for the "role3".

**Question:**
What is the best way to do that ?
I can make a query using something like the LIKE operator for all itens of my java list:

```
//javaList collection has 3 items: "role3", "role4" and "role5"
for (String role: javaList) {
    query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    query.should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("roles", "*" + role + "*"));
    response = client.prepareSearch(indexName).setQuery(query).setTypes(type).execute().actionGet();
    hits = response.getHits();
}
```

And then iterate over each hit, but this sounds like a very bad apporach, because the javaList can have more than 20 itens, that would mean 20 querys to elastic.

I need a way to tell this to Elastic:

```
This is my list of roles, query internally and retrieve
only the records that matches at least one of those roles.
```

In order to do that I understand I can't index that data as a String right ? Ideally would be to have it an array or something like it...

How can I do that in the most performatic way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely you should not use wildcard query in a loop. This solution eventually will demonstrate a poor performance.

Since `roles` field is a regular text field Elasticsearch splits value "role1;role2;role3" into individual tokens "role1", "role2" and "role3". The same operation is applied to a search query. You can use simple match query with query string "role3;role4;role5" and get hit because of "role3" token match.

Also you can index `roles` field as an array of strings and the same match query will still work.